# How to define a default constructor by code using StructureMap?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I can't figure out how to define the default constructor (when it exists overloads) for a type in StructureMap (version 2.5) by code.

I want to get an instance of a service and the container has to inject a Linq2Sql data context instance into it.

I wrote this in my 'bootstrapper' method :

```
ForRequestedType<MyDataContext>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<MyDataContext>();
```

When I run my app, I got this error :

> StructureMap Exception Code:  202
>   No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily MyNamespace.Data.SqlRepository.MyDataContext, MyNamespace.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

If I comment out all Linq2Sql generated contructors that I don't need, it works fine.

Update : Oh, and I forgot to say that I would not use the `[StructureMap.DefaultConstructor]` attribute.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can specify a constructor with the ConstructedBy(). Please try this:

```
ForRequestedType<MyDataContext>().TheDefault.
Is.ConstructedBy(() => new MyDataContext());
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Updated SM 2.6 Syntax: For<MyDataContext>().Use(() => new MyDataContext());

Comment: It appears in SM 2.6.2 that the Use does not have any constructor arguments.

Comment: Tested in SM 2.6.4.1: For<IFoo>().Use(() => new Foo());

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you'd also need to set the object lifetime (InstanceScope) if you are using Linq2Sql.  I'd suggest using this code because it give you a little more flexibility.

```
ForRequestedType< MyDataContext >()
            .CacheBy( InstanceScope.PerRequest )
            .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType< MyDataContext >()

SelectConstructor< MyDataContext >( () => new MyDataContext());
```

With this code you can also further inject interfaces definitions into the MyDataContext constructor like this

```
SelectConstructor< MyDataContext >( () => new MyDataContext((IDatabaseFactory)null ));
```

Just remember to define the concrete type with StructureMap for your IDatabaseFactory instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how / if it can be done with the fluent interface / internal DSL. You can however use an attribute, if you're not fussed about *polluting your domain*?

Tag your preferred constructor with [DefaultConstructor] StructureMap defaults to the greediest constructor by convention (constructor with the most parameters).

Comment: Sorry Cik, I'd already typed (but not submitted) my response during your update.

Comment: No problem, my fault ;-) Thanks for your reply anyway !

The approach of annotating my DataContext (in creating a partial class) would be possible but I think that it looses from the benefit of using an IoC ...