# Tell StructureMap to use a specific constructor

Tags: c#, structuremap, xmlreader, xpathdocument

I have two services that require an `XPathDocument`. I want to be able to define named instances of `XPathDocumnet` to use in the configuration of the two services. I also want to be able to tell StuctureMap which constructor of `XPathDocument` to use. When I try to get an instance of `XPathDocument` it tells me that it can't find the plugged type for `XmlReader`. I want to use the constructor that requires a string uri for the xml file. I cannot seem to get this to work. Here is the StructureMap configuration code.

```
public class Service1 : IService1 {
    public Service1(XPathDocument document) {}
}
public class Service2 : IService2 {
    public Service2(XPathDocument document) {}
}

public class Registry1 : Registry {
    ForRequestedType<IService1>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Service1>()
        .CtorDependency<XPathDocument>()
        .Is(x => x.TheInstanceNamed("XPathDocument1"));
    ForRequestedType<IService2>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Service2>()
        .CtorDependency<XPathDocument>()
        .Is(x => x.TheInstanceNamed("XPathDocument2"));

    ForRequestedType<XPathDocument>().AddInstances(x => {
        x.OfConcreteType<XPathDocument>()
            .WithCtorArg("uri").EqualToAppSetting("XmlFile1")
            .WithName("XPathDocument1");
        x.OfConcreteType<XPathDocument>()
            .WithCtorArg("uri").EqualToAppSetting("XmlFile2")
            .WithName("XPathDocument2");
    });
}
```

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289512/structuremap-how-to-define-default-constructor-by-code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289512/structuremap-how-to-define-default-constructor-by-code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [StructureMap : How to define default constructor by code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289512/structuremap-how-to-define-default-constructor-by-code)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289512/structuremap-how-to-define-default-constructor-by-code). In short, you need to change `OfConcreteType<Service1>()` to `ConstructedBy(() => new Service1());`.