# Define Default constructor Structuremap in a Generic Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, dependency-injection, structuremap, ioc-container

I have a generic IRepository that has 2 constructors, one have none parameters, other has the datacontext as parameter.
I want to define to structuremap to aways in this case use the parameterless constructor. 
I want a way to create a parameterless contructor, other solutions that I have seen, they create a new Datacontext and pass it to the constructor that has parameters.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289512/structuremap-how-to-define-default-constructor-by-code

Comment: Does not becaouse I'm using a generic repository! I need to do something like this: x.SelectConstructor(IRepository<T>.......

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Interfaces do not have constructors.

Comment: Sorry my mistake: It should look like this:

 x.SelectConstructor<Repository<T>>(()=> new Repository<T>()); 
but this does not work...any way to make this work?

Comment: Why do you want a parameterless constructor? The whole point of DI is that the container will provide the concrete implementation of the interface parameters on your constructor.

Answer (score 4):

By default, StructureMap will use the constructor with the most arguments.  In your case, since you want it to use the parameterless constructor, use the `DefaultConstructorAttribute`:

```
[DefaultConstructor]
public void Repository<T>() { }

public void Repository<T>(DataContext dataContext) { }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in any other way? It would appear, without access/desire to add an attrbiute to your class you can't specify a default constructor for open generic types because you can't formulate a constructor expression with them.

Comment: You can configure StructureMap to call the other constructor explicitly, too.  If I couldn't modify the class in question that's the approach I would take.

Comment: But you can't actually call the constructor of an open generic e.g. BaseClass<TType, TProperty> etc because you can't compile an expression that doesn't fulfill those parameters.