# StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily

Tags: c#, asp.net, structuremap

I am new to StructureMap. I have downloaded and am 
using version 2.6.1.0. I keep getting the below 
error:

> StructureMap Exception Code:  202 No
>   Default Instance defined for
>   PluginFamily
>   Company.ProjectCore.Core.IConfiguration,
>   Company.ProjectCore, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

My Global.asax.cs looks like:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var container = new Container(x =>
                    {
                        x.For<ICache>().Use<Cache>();
                        x.For<IEmailService>().Use<EmailService>();
                        x.For<IUserSession>().Use<UserSession>();
                        x.For<IRedirector>().Use<Redirector>();
                        x.For<INavigation>().Use<Navigation>();
                    });

                container.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

}
```

I changed from ObjectFactory.Initialize to "new Container" to debug. 
When stepping through the AssertConfigurationIsValid() method, Cache
works but EmailService fails at the GetInstance method in the 
following line:

```
[Pluggable("Default")]
public class EmailService : IEmailService

private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public EmailService()
{
    _configuration = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IConfiguration>();
}
```

If I remove IEmailService, the same 202 error is thrown at IUserSession.

Should I be adding something else in Application_Start or in my class files?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What application layer does StructureMap belong to? UI, Business, or Data layer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This problem was fixed by replacing `ObjectFactory.Initialize` with `ObjectFactory.Configure` and adding the assemblies in my project:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.LookForRegistries();
        scan.Assembly("MyAssembly");
        scan.Assembly("MyAssembly");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It work good. Can u mark it as answer please. Because its easy for the reader.

Comment: I had the same error message. The reason for my issue was that StructureMap couldn't find the implementation of the interface because of the Default ISomething/Something Convention (refer to https://structuremap.github.io/registration/auto-registration-and-conventions/). Once I change the implmentation name to be matched with interface name, it worked.

Answer (score 15):

I was getting the same error message, but for a different reason.  I had a class Foo that defined two constructors like so:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private Bar _bar;

    public Foo()
    {
       _bar = new Bar();
    }

    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }
}
```

and my StructureMap configuration was like so:

```
For<IFoo>.Use<Foo>();
```

I kept getting an error message like

> 202 No Default Instance defined for Bar

The problem was that StructureMap was trying to construct a Foo using the constructor that takes a parameter, instead of using the parameterless default constructor.  I solved it using the answer in [How to define a default constructor by code using StructureMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298392/456814) like so:

```
For<IFoo>.Use(() => new Foo());
```

Answer (score 6):

Where's your bootstrapping for the IConfiguration concrete class?

I.e:

```
x.For<IConfiguration>().Use<Configuration>();
```

Comment: Yeah.. I tried adding that and it doesn't seem to matter. When it is there, it is never hit. When I comment out all other classes, the compiler acts as if it is not there and just goes to the next block of code. Also, as I pointed out before, if I take out IEmailService (where IConfiguration is called) the next interface - IUserSession - gets called and I get the 202 error again. So, I don't think the answer to my problem is how I am bootstrapping IConfiguration.

Comment: The answer to your problem is certainly how you are bootstrapping. StructureMap error 202 means you haven't told StructureMap how to resolve a dependency (in your bootstrapping). In this specific case, you never told it how to resolve an IConfiguration.

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing the same error. In my case, I had a typo in the implementation name, so the interface and implementation names did not match.

```
public class FooTypo : IFoo
```

Where I should have had:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
```

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to look for is to make sure that the dependency (class) that you are injecting is **public**. If the class is internal, it can cause this issue.

Comment: My class constructor was 'protected', changing to public did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was because I had accidentally referenced the concrete type in the constructor of another class rather than the interface

eg in structuremap i had

```
x.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>();
x.For<IBar>().Use<Bar>();
```

and constructor for Foo looked like this

```
public class Foo : IFoo {
    public Foo(Bar bar) {...}
}
```

when it should have looked like this as SM couldn't just create an instance of Bar, it only knows how to make an IBar:

```
public class Foo : IFoo {
    public Foo(IBar bar) {...}
}
```

It also meant that my exception referenced the concrete type instead of the interface but I missed that initially

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error it was because I forgot to mark my class `public`. That simple.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue when I was using Visual Studio 2015 with NCrunch.
All you have to do is toggle an option to **true** in the configuration menu item under NCrunch. Switching initialize to configure didn't work for me.

The option is under Build Settings, it is named '*Copy referenced assemblies to workspace*'

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same error. In my case, I had a typo in the implementation with the same name of another class in another project.