# How to use structuremap for Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, structuremap

Using the following Generic Repository.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    void Commit();
    void Delete(T item);
    IQueryable<T> Find();
    IList<T> FindAll();
    void Add(T item);     
}
```

How do you code structuremap to use it?  I'm using Structuremap v 2.6.1 for .net 3.5

```
public static void BootstrapStructureMap()
{
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
    {                   
        // This is giving me problems!
        x.For<IRepository<Employee>>().Use<IRepository<Employee>>(); 
    });
}
```

I get the following error:

**StructureMap Exception Code 202
No default instance defined for plugin family**

Comment: possible duplicate of [StructureMap Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910493/structuremap-exception-code-202-no-default-instance-defined-for-pluginfamily)

Comment: Nope Still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `For().Use()` construct, you tell StructureMap to instantiate the type given in the `Use` when someone requests the type in the `For`. So typically, you supply the `For` with an interface or abstract base class, since you program against abstractions.

The problem here is that you passed in an abstract type (your `IRepository<T>`) into the `Use` method. StructureMap will be unable to create a new instance of that interface. You need to create a generic implementation of `IRepository<T>` (`EntityFrameworkRepository<T>` for instance) and register that. Example:

```
x.For<IRepository<Employee>>().Use<EntityFrameworkRepository<Employee>>();
```

This however will pretty soon lead to a lot of registrations, since you will have a dozen of repositories that you want to use. So instead of making many registrations for every closed generic repository you want to use, you can reduce this to a single registration using the open generic type, as follows:

```
x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(EntityFrameworkRepository<>)));
```